# Remove exception with bean creation on integration test, which does not appear on standard application start

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have spring boot application which works well, but when I started to work on integration tests, I discovered, that there is cyclic dependency in project:

```
@Service
public class CrowdManagerSyncService {
    private final CrowdManagerSyncScheduler crowdManagerSyncScheduler;

    @Autowired
    public CrowdManagerSyncService(CrowdManagerSyncScheduler crowdManagerSyncScheduler) {
        this.crowdManagerSyncScheduler = Objects.requireNonNull(crowdManagerSyncScheduler);
    }
}
```

And

```
@Component
public class CrowdManagerSyncScheduler {
    @Autowired
    private CrowdManagerSyncService crowdManagerSyncService;
}
```

It is not my code and I am not ready to rewrite it right now. But it works perfectly well in production. In my integration test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
@WithMockUser(roles={"ADMIN"})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AdminConsoleApplication.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        MockMvcAutoConfiguration.class, MockMvcWebDriverAutoConfiguration.class})
public class UserControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvcHtmlUnitDriverBuilder builder;
    private WebDriver webDriver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        webDriver = builder.build();
    }
}
```

I catch exception:

> Error creating bean with name 'crowdManagerSyncService': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

So, my question is: how to omit this problem in testing without removing that awful circular dependency? It works well in production, so pretty sure there is some way to start test context without code change.

Comment: Can you attach a stack trace ? Spring Boot version ...

Comment: @Babl Here is my stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/VYXh0vgh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@WebMvcTest` is not suitable for "proper" integration tests.

From [the api docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html):

> Can be used when a test focuses **only** on Spring MVC components.

However, you're then using `@ContextConfiguration` to essentially add your whole application to the test.

Remove the `@ContextConfiguration` and instead autowire a `@MockBean` `CrowdManagerSyncService` into your test.
This creates a mock version of `CrowdManagerSyncService` and injects it into the `UserController` in the test application context.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
@WithMockUser(roles={"ADMIN"})
public class UserControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvcHtmlUnitDriverBuilder builder;

    @MockBean
    private CrowdManagerSyncService service;

    private WebDriver webDriver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        webDriver = builder.build();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldWork() {
        when(service.doStuff())
            .thenReturn("Hello"); // regular Mockito mocking
    }
}
```

This is appropriate if you're just trying to test the `UserController` and sidesteps the circular dependency problem because there's no instantiation of a "real" `CrowdManagerSyncService` anywhere.

You can also replace `@WebMvcTest` and `@ContextConfiguration` with both `@SpringBootTest` (which bootstraps the application just like production) and `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` (which replaces the real HTTP stuff with MockMvc).

Comment: Thank you! `@SpringBootTest(classes = AdminConsoleApplication.class)` and `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` really helped me!